# Индексация страниц роботами, express+pug+ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, pug, индексация

Нужен совет сейчас создаем ТЗ для блога, по дизайну решили выводить все страницы с помощью ajax с базы. По функционалу задумывали собирать все pug шаблонизатором и выводить статьи с помощью ajax + express, но закрался вопрос как эта вундервафля будет индексироватся роботами так как с ajax-ом они не сильно дружат, я не до конца понимаю алгоритмы роботов, кто может что-то подсказать буду очень благодарен.

Comment: По сути для блога зачем использовать такую связку ,как ajax + express?

Comment: Заказчик хочет реализацию подгрузки статей не по страницами а Аяксом при скроле, как новости в фб или вк